# Load data from php request as needed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the chosen jquery plugin which turns a multi slect box into a facebook style selector. I am filling it with UK postcodes as well as displaying selected postcodes as well.

As my PHP request is retrieving a lot of data from my postcode database the page obviously runs quite slow, but I want to be able to only retrieve data once the user has entered 1 character in the input box.

I know I will have to do it with Ajax and I think JSON, but now sure how?

Here is my code

```
    <select name="zipcode[]" style="width:600px; height:250px;" multiple class="chzn-select" id="zipcode">

          <?php $arraypostcode = explode(",", $zipcode); ?>
    <?php
do { // begin loop
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_postcode['code']?>"<?php for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arraypostcode); $i++) {if ($row_postcode['code'] == $arraypostcode[$i]) {echo " selected"; break;}}?>><?php echo $row_postcode['code']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_postcode = mysql_fetch_assoc($postcode)); // end loop
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($postcode);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($postcode, 0);
      $row_postcode = mysql_fetch_assoc($postcode);
  }
?>
  </select>
```

PHP request:

```
<?php

$postcode = mysql_query( "SELECT postcode.code FROM postcode");
$row_postcode = mysql_fetch_assoc($postcode);
$totalRows_postcode = mysql_num_rows($postcode);

?>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Side note: Triggering the request on 1 key entered could be to generic  maybe try firing it after 3 or more chars, to be able to do this. Keep it simple try jquery.ajax  and trigger the input on keyup.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax:

you can run

`$postcode = mysql_query( "SELECT postcode.code FROM postcode WHERE code LIKE 'YOUR_USER_VALUE%'");
$row_postcode = mysql_fetch_assoc($postcode);
$totalRows_postcode = mysql_num_rows($postcode);`

you have to run this every time user inputs a character

LIKE 'VALUE%' this in sql pretty much means startsWith("VALUE") if you are familiar with other programming languages as java or something.

If you value is stored as numeric then you would have to cast:
`cast(code as char)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines.

On form Page:

```
<input type="text" name="postcodeSearch" onChange="getPostcodes(this.value); return false;">
<div id="postcodeSelector"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getPostcodes(input){
    if(input.length >= 3){
        searchPostcodes(input);
    }
}

function searchPostcodes(input){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/url/to/postcodeSearch',
        data: "input=" + input,
        dataType: 'html',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $("#postcodeSelector").html(data);
        }
    }
}
```

On /usr/to/postcodeSearch page:

```
$input = $_GET["input"];

## Do database search with 'input' string
$postcodes = $somedbconnection->searchPostcodes($input);
?>
<select name="postcode">
    <? foreach($postcodes as $postcode){ ?>
        <option value='<?=$postcode["id"]?>'><?=$postcode["postcode"]?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```